# Share 3D map between different HoloLens

Tags: hololens

I use one HoloLens to create a detailed map. I can export it via device portal. I want to konw can I share it with other HoloLens?

Thanks.

YL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also import it via Device Portal, please refer to [Exporting and importing maps - Mixed Reality | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/advanced-concepts/using-the-windows-device-portal#exporting-and-importing-maps).